# How do I implement an interface if I don't need all of its functions?

Tags: c#

I have a simple interface defined

```
public interface IBla
{
    public void DoThing();
    public void DoAnotherThing();
    public void Thing();
}
```

I have a bunch of classes which implement this interface. Lots of them however only need two of the three functions which that interface implements, so currently I implement the remaining ones as well and just leave them empty like so:

```
public void DoThing(){}
```

Is there some more elegant way of doing this?
I do **NOT** want to have multiple interfaces defined for this. 
Is there perhaps something like a "partialInterface" where I don't have to implement all of the functions from that interface into a class which implements that interface?

Thanks

Comment: You can use an abstract class

Comment: Explicit interface implementation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173157.aspx

Comment: Can I ask why you don't want to have specific interfaces that inherit from a base interface? Seems like a code smell to me that will become difficult to manage in the long term.

Comment: Have you considered separating that interface up into more than one?

Comment: @juharr the OP specifically asks for a solution without separating the interface...

Comment: That doesn't mean that isn't the right answer. It definitely sounds like his interface is breaking the S in SOLID. Not only is it a calculator, it is also a ruler, a swiss army knife, a toothbrush, and an umbrella. Those are different things requiring different interfaces, the actual *implementing type* is the one that brings them all together but you would never make a ICalculatorRulerSwissArmyKnifeToothbrushUmbrella interface. On the other hand, that's now going to be my default name for an interface that is hard to name because it breaks the S in SOLID.

Comment: Also agree with others.  If you're finding most implementations aren't fully implementing your interface, its a sign your design is flawed and needs reworking.

Comment: A partial interface is an oxymoron. The interface is a contract that implementations contain all of the functionality.

Comment: I haven't added that condition on a whim, I am using this code as part of a game loop and without going into long details, I have to fetch the interface during every frame (which is expensive), so if I have the cleaner solution, with multiple interfaces, and fetch 20 interfaces during every frame instead, it will be like throwing performance into a sewer. (Under "normal" circumstances, I would simply used multiple interfaces as you suggested)

Comment: I think you'll have to go into details as I'm not sure what you mean by "fetch the interface".  Are you saying you're using reflection?  In general it just sounds like there are design issues if having multiple interfaces causes major performance problems.

Comment: It is an engine specific thing, which is out of this question's scope.

Comment: No, what youve described is an XY Problem. You *think* having multiple interfaces will cause you a performance problem, so you want to avoid it. Whats almost certainly the problem is the way you *use* those interfaces. Giving more/different detail may provide you with a better solution, which does not require you to partially implemtn/throw NotSupportedException

Comment: In this case it's not the Single Responsibility Principle, although it's very closely related. It's the Interface Segregation Principle. Even if a hypothetical class does too many things, it can still implement a more concise interface that only exposes certain members. It doesn't solve the class's SRP problem, but by depending on the "segregated" interface other classes can ignore all the members they don't care about.

Comment: in most cases interfaces are not needed, think about this who uses your code, no one, so don't waste time trying to implement the best interfaces, interfaces just add more complexity to the project and you end up with more functional errors than there should be

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When implementing an interface, the type that implements the interface must provide an implementation for **everything** that interface details.

There is no support for partial interfaces or anything similar to what you want, other than breaking up the interface.

You're basically asking "How can I implement the calculator interface without requiring me to provide the `+` operator" and in short, you can't. It would no longer be a calculator *according to that interface*.

The closest thing you get is that you can create a base class that provides default implementations for the whole interface or parts of it, and inherit from this base type, so that inherited classes become *easier* to implement with less code, but they *will* provide the entire interface.

Answer (score 2):

I know you said *you* don't want separate interfaces, but for the benefit of others in future who want the *right* answer to this question here it is:

---

What you describe is the point at which you separate your interfaces out, and use interface inheritance.

```
public interface IBasic
{
    void DoThing();
}

public interface IAdvanced : IBasic
{
    void DoAnotherThing();
    void Thing();
}
```

Implementations which only need `DoThing` only implement `IBasic`. Implementations which need all functionality implement `IAdvanced` which includes the method from `IBasic` plus the additional functionality.

Answer (score 0):

If you have classes which implement not all methods, then you probably need to separate this interface into smaller interfaces.
Many specific interfaces are better than one universal.

Creating the classes which implement your interface, and throw `NotImplementedException` or simply do nothing looks like SOLID rules violation.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it is highly discouraged to only partially implement an interface, there is a way to sort of do it.

Most answers talk about breaking up your interface into multiple interfaces, which makes sense. But, if this is not possible simply implement the members that you do not want to use in an explicit manner, and if they get called you should throw a `NotSupportedException`.

---

If you want to see an example of this in use, look no further than Microsoft's own code: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/objectmodel/readonlycollection.cs

```
void ICollection<T>.Add(T value)
{
    ThrowHelper.ThrowNotSupportedException(ExceptionResource.NotSupported_ReadOnlyCollection);
}
```

Comment: Bit of a special case though, isn't it. Yes a `ReadOnlyCollection` can most of the things that any other collection can do, except (for example) add new entries. However it makes sense that this collection implement `ICollection` so it can do all the *other* things a collection can do. As I said - a very special case with a very clear meaning - not the same as "I designed my interfaces wrong, and now ive coded myself into a corner"

Comment: @jmiec actually that *is* a case where MS designed their interfaces wrong and were stuck in a corner.  The solution is to have interfaces for reading collections, and then writable versions that extend them.  MS simply didn't realize their mistake until it was too late to fix much of it.

Answer (score 0):

Given that these things are being processed in a game loop, presumably implementations of `IBla` are things like the player character, enemies, obstacles, missiles and the like and `DoThing` etc and `Move`, `Fire` and so forth.

If so, then your approach is perfectly valid. An immobile object should have a `Move` method (so the game loop can call it), and since it can't move, an empty method is a valid implementation.

Answer (score 0):

If you control both interfaces then separate the interfaces into multiple interfaces. As suggested, one interface can inherit from the other, or you could just have some classes implement both interfaces.

In this case interface inheritance is probably the better choice because you won't have to modify the classes that already implement the larger interface.

What if the larger interface is one you don't control, so splitting it into multiple interfaces isn't an option? It's not a good idea to implement the interface and leave some methods without implementations. If a class implements an interface then it should *really* implement the interface.

A solution is to define the smaller interface that you actually want and create a class that adapts the larger interface to your smaller one.

Suppose you have this interface

```
public interface IDoesFourThings
{
    void DoThingOne();
    void DoThingTwo();
    void DoThingThree();
    void DoThingFour();
}
```

And you want a class that only implements two of those things? You shouldn't implement `IDoesFourThings` if the class really only does two things.

So first, create your own interface:

```
public interface IDoesTwoThings
{
    void DoThingA();
    void DoThingB();
}
```

Then create a class that adapts an implementation of `IDoesFourThings` to your interface.

```
public class DoesTwoThingsUsingClassThatDoesFourThings : IDoesTwoThings
{
    private readonly IDoesFourThings _doesFourThings;

    public DoesTwoThingsUsingClassThatDoesFourThings(IDoesFourThings doesFourThings)
    {
        _doesFourThings = doesFourThings;
    }

    public void DoThingA()
    {
        _doesFourThings.DoThingTwo();
    }

    public void DoThingB()
    {
        _doesFourThings.DoThingThree();
    }
}
```

Just for the sake of example I avoided naming the methods in `IDoesTwoThings` to match the ones in `IDoesFourThings`. Unless they're really exactly the same thing then the new interface doesn't need to match the old one. It is its own interface. That the class works by using an inner implementation of `IDoesFourThings` is hidden.

This relates to the [Interface Segregation Principle](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/solid-part-3-liskov-substitution-interface-segregation-principles--net-36710), the I in SOLID. One way of thinking about it is this: An interface describes what a class does, but from the perspective of the client class it should describe *what the client needs*. In this case the client needs two things, not four.

This approach can be very helpful because it enables us to work on one class at a time and defer the implementation of other details. If we're writing a class and we realize that it's going to require a dependency that does two things, we can just write the interface for those two things and make our class depend on it. (Now that class is more testable because it depends on an interface which we can mock.) Then, whatever that new interface is that we just created, we can also create an implementation for that.

It's a great way to manage the complexity of writing code and avoid getting stuck because now we can just work on our one class with its single responsibility, not worrying too much about how the next class and the next one will work. (We likely have an idea how they will work, but maybe we don't. Either way it doesn't slow us down.)